# newsletter mass send emails

Tags: c#, asp.net

Having a little trouble with my Newsletter...

Let me explain:
I have a sql table with my emails and nothing else and a sql table where i store the mails after they have been sendt, somehow the mails wont sent, but it will save the mails.

it is all set up in a formview.

```
protected void btnSendNewsLetter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox subject = (TextBox)fvNewsletter.Row.FindControl("txtSubject");
        TextBox body = (TextBox)fvNewsletter.Row.FindControl("txtBody");

        string connection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GreenCollaborationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select Email from MailingList", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        GreenDataSet ds1 = new GreenDataSet();
        da1.Fill(ds1);
        if(ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                string email = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                mail.From = new MailAddress("noreply@GreenCollaboration.com", "GreenCollaboration");
                mail.To.Add(email);
                mail.Subject = subject.Text;
                mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = body.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

i hope some1 can help me :)

Comment: I don't see where you are actually sending the message?

Comment: Where's the code that does the actual sending of the message ?

Comment: Don't forget to `Dispose` those SQL objects.

Comment: And, a suggestion: don't render/send emails from your main thread (ie: button_onClick); it's a fairly long operation that will lessen the user experience. Add the emails to a queue (in the database) and have a separate thread (process, task, etc.) render and send them out

Comment: Since you are sending the same message to multiple recipients, why not just add all the email addresses to the bcc of the email and then you only need to build one email message and send it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
protected void btnSendNewsLetter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //snip

    //Create the smtp client to send the mails with.
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
    // Add credentials if the SMTP server requires them.
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    if(ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            string email = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            //snip
            try 
            {
                client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());             
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Msdn MailMessage Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx#exampleToggle)

Answer (score 0):

Erm... it seems as though you are simply missing the following:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```

put it on the line following:

```
mail.Body = body.Text;
```

and put the following details in your web.config

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="test@foo.com">
      <network host="smtpserver1" port="25" userName="username" password="secret" defaultCredentials="true" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Edit: Which addresses the immediate problem of not sending emails.

However as noted elsewhere to send email en mass you should do a more robust implementation e.g. see [this link for a mass email sender example](http://www.emailarchitect.net/webapp/smtpcom/developers/netpool.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You generated the messages but never actually sent them. There are few different mechanisms to send, like SMTP or Exchange

So if you were planning to use SMTP

```
//Somewhere on top
var server="EMAIL.CORP.COMPANY" //or "10.10.10.10"
var smtpClient= new SmtpClient(server);
smtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; //AD credentials

//In the end of your for loop
try {
    smtpClient.Send(mail);
catch (Exception ex) {
    //Handle the exception    
}
```